# how to rotate a button in the same position iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uibutton, rotation

i have i button, by adding animations i am moving my button from one position to another position, before moving to specified position i want to rotate my button in circle position.

i have one idea about animations and searched in web, no solution works. i wrote below code for moving, can any one please tell me how to add rotation for a button

```
    CGRect fr1 = CGRectMake(143, 429, 25, 25);
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(121, 381, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveToRight:finished:context:)];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [button setFrame:fr1];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cabasic animation for rotating on ownaxis..This will work for you.